# Java Based Configuration of Spring MVC project gives "The requested resource is not available."

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, jboss, spring-annotations

Update: The project works in tomcat, I just wasn't browsing to the right url. This seems to be a JBoss problem.

I have been trying to follow the steps in this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/

The login/logout page is accessible, and accessing a restricted page redirects to the login page correctly, but when I log in, I get a 404 error and "JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available." I have tried running the project on JBoss and Tomcat. Here are all the files I'm using:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.shit</groupId>
    <artifactId>thing</artifactId>
    <name>SecurityTest</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

AppConfig.java:

```
package com.shit.thing.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.shit.thing.**" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver 
                          = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
package com.shit.thing.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mkyong").password("123456").roles("USER");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("123456").roles("DBA");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/dba/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA')")
        .and().formLogin();

    }
}
```

SecurityInitializer.java:

```
package com.shit.thing.core;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
   //do nothing
}
```

SpringMvcInitializer.java:

```
package com.shit.thing.core;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.shit.thing.config.AppConfig;

public class SpringMvcInitializer 
       extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

HelloController.java:

```
package com.shit.thing.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - Admin Page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dba**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView dbaPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - Database Page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

}
```

admin.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} 
                 | <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />" > Logout</a></h2>  
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>   
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not really sure how to start debugging this, since I get no descriptive errors.

Startup Logs:

```
11:16:11,184 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
11:16:11,498 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
11:16:11,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
11:16:12,679 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015002: Deployment of 'SpringProject.war' requested, but the deployment is not present
11:16:12,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Rentflix.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Rentflix.war.dodeploy
11:16:12,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found SecurityTest.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called SecurityTest.war.dodeploy
11:16:12,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Copy of SecurityTest.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Copy of SecurityTest.war.dodeploy
11:16:12,707 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:16:12,711 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:16:12,717 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:16:12,729 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
11:16:12,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:16:12,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
11:16:12,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1
11:16:12,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:16:12,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:16:12,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
11:16:12,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
11:16:13,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:16:13,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:16:13,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:16:13,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:16:13,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
11:16:13,105 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]): org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:561) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl$ContextServiceBuilder.install(OperationContextImpl.java:1413) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.startDriverServices(JdbcDriverAdd.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:76) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:607) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:485) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:282) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:277) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:343) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]

11:16:13,498 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:16:13,515 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:16:13,766 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) "JBAS014784: Failed executing subsystem datasources boot operations"
11:16:13,790 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
11:16:13,800 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files (x86)\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments
11:16:13,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SecurityTest.war" (runtime-name: "SecurityTest.war")
11:16:13,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
11:16:14,051 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443
11:16:14,052 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443
11:16:14,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
11:16:15,228 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:16:15,389 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) JBAS018210: Register web context: /SecurityTest
11:16:15,424 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SecurityTest]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.shit.thing.core.SpringMvcInitializer@3759b60a, com.shit.thing.core.SecurityInitializer@62be66e9]
11:16:15,555 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SecurityTest]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:16:16,450 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SecurityTest]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
11:16:16,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "SecurityTest.war" (runtime-name : "SecurityTest.war")
```

Comment: Show us your startup logs. Are the controllers registered?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited that in, think that's what you're referring to. I don't know what you mean by the controllers being registered.

Comment: You should enable Spring logs. Spring will say when it registers controllers as handlers for requests.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your standalone.xml in jboss server
virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false"> 
use false instead of true in enable-welcome-root, if this doesn't work check out web.xml and look out whether the controller entry is correct over there or not.

Comment: I tried changing the settings in standalone.xml, and it does the same thing. The project doesn't have a web.xml file.

Comment: If you don't have web.xml,Then how you are invoking dispatcher servlet which is controller in case of spring.

Comment: I am not sure, still new to this. The tutorial I'm following doesn't have a web.xml

Comment: use this web.xml template ---

Comment: When I add that xml, it gives: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.

Comment: My bad, you are using WebApplicationInitializer so web.xml is not required

Comment: Please check whether you are putting the jsp's in webapp\WEB-INF\views folder.

Comment: Yes they are in there. I just found that this project works when I run it under tomcat, so it appears to be a jboss issue...

Answer (score 0):

use this as web.xml template to initialize application context and to load dispatcher servlet ---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>security-services</display-name>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```